# How to call ruby function more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ruby text that fetches a random row from a SQL database of quotes,
and later I use javascript to display this random quote on button click:
My issue is that I would like to generate a NEW random quote whenever the button is pressed. I have been told I can do this using jQuery, but I've very lost as to how to go about this.

In a controller:

```
random_offset = rand(Quote.count - 1)
@random_quote = Quote.offset(random_offset).first
```

Javascript:

```
var generatedQuote = '"<%= @random_quote.quote %>" <br>  - <%= @random_quote.author %>'

function populateQuote(){
  $("#quoteArea").val(generatedQuote);
  $("#imagewrap h3").html(generatedQuote);
}

var quoteButton = document.getElementById('randomQuote');
quoteButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
  populateQuote();
});
```

Comment: move the first row (var generatedQuote......) inside the function populateQuote()

Comment: Tried this but the generatedQuote variable doesn't generate the quote, the controller text does. This only renders it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render all the quotes and randomize clientside. Javascript :

```
var quotes = <%= raw Quote.all.map {|q| [q.quote, q.author]}.to_json %>;
var random_quote = function(){
  var quote_item = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
  return '"'+quote_item[0]+'" <br>  - '+quote_item[1];
};

$("#randomQuote").click(function(){
  var new_random_quote= random_quote();
  $("#quoteArea").val(new_random_quote);
  $("#imagewrap h3").html(new_random_quote);
});
```

Or you should fetch the server with each click on the button, depending on the number of quotes available / what you prefer for your web app.

Comment: Other than adding this, is there anything that has to be changed? After adding this in, the function on button click still only works once. Any ideas? Thanks so much for the response.

Comment: also, the database contains around 75,000 quotes. Which method is better in this case?

Comment: Ok you should have remove all your code (controller + javascript) and replace it with this.
This would put all the 75,000 quotes in a JS var so this is too much i guess. You should create a system that fetch a new random quote from the server into the populateQuote() function

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.